# Calculating CRC8 in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

So sadly I have to admit that I gave up on 8 hour search for the correct CRC8 code in VBA programming language.
There are many examples, but yet I haven't find the one that works in my case. So here I am, asking you for help, if someone can write me this part of code, or if there's a misterious link, that I haven't clicked on.

**Explanation:**

```
AppID = "A00000039656434103F0154020D4000A"
```

In my project, it is required that char "A" is at the end of this AppID, since based on this the CRC8 should be calculated. If understand correct (cause I might have gone insane during entire day of trying to write this CRC8 function) I have `32-byte` ID, on which I want to do the CRC8 check on the `16bits` (does this make sense?)

In the given example, I have only the result of what the CRC8 should return:

```
CRC8 = 0x6D
```

And I need to replace the lower nible with the char "A" in my main AppID:

```
FinalAppID = "A00000039656434103F0154020D4000D"
```

**PROBLEM:** But I simply don't know how to write nor to convert the codes from C++ / C#. And I was really strick with step by step conversion, yet it didn't work.

**This is the code I use:**

```
Public function calculateCRC8(ByVal AppID As String ) As String
    Dim CRC8 As Byte
    Dim i as Integer
    Dim j as Integer
    Dim AppIDarray()


    CRC8 = &HC7; //Based on preset 0xE3 
    aidLenght = LEN(AppID)
    AppIDarray = StringToArray(AppID) ' I user a UDF that I wrote, this should work OK'
            For j = 0 To aidLenght
                CRC8 = CRC8 Xor AppIDarray(j) 
                For i = 1 To 8 
                    If CRC8 And &H80 Then
                     CRC8 = (CRC8 * 2) Xor &H1D
                    Else
                     CRC8 = CRC8 * 2
                    End If  
                next i
            Next j
    calculateCRC8 = CRC8
End Function
```

*I'm not in office now, so there might by typos in the above code, or some silly mistakes, I wrote it just now by my head, as I worked with it entire day.*

The problem that occurs with above code is:

**Error:**

```
Error: Overflow!
```

This error occurs even if I pass the `entire string`, or just the `16bits`. Same error.

If anyone has anything to help me out here, I will be really grateful to him!

Comment: Do you know which line causes the overflow? Are you sure your UDF works ok?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet @James I am not that good VBA, just started recently to code in it, only due to this "little" project as they told me. I'm not great yet at debugging. But, when I MsgBox-ed CRC8.. I got some weird number ..like big negative numbers. 
I will double check again the StringToArray function..but I think it works fine, I did some testing.
I also tried to turn OFF the Error Message, but I can't find the option to do so ? I dont have this Solution Explorer that is mentioned in every link on web, when I search for how to turn it OFF.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but you really need to replace it with the ***actual*** code and let us know where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a version of with a few fixes and it prevents the overflow from happening.  It generates the expected result (&H6D) for your hex bytes (A00000039656434103F0154020D4000A).

```
Public Function calculateCRC8(ByVal AppID As String) As String
    Dim CRC8 As Byte
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim AppIDarray() As Byte  '<--- explicitly dimensioned as a Byte array to avoid confusion


    CRC8 = &HC7  

    'The AppID is actually bytes stored in hexadecimal in a string. You have to convert them back to bytes before you can run a crc8 on them.
    AppIDarray = HexToByte(AppID)
    aidLength = UBound(AppIDarray)
            For j = 0 To aidLength
                CRC8 = CRC8 Xor AppIDarray(j)
                For i = 1 To 8
                    If CRC8 And &H80 Then
                     'masking off the left-most bit before shifting prevents the Overflow error.
                     CRC8 = ((&H7F And CRC8) * 2) Xor &H1D
                    Else
                     CRC8 = CRC8 * 2
                    End If
                Next i
            Next j
    calculateCRC8 = CRC8
End Function
```

This function takes a hexadecimal string and interprets it as a `Byte` array.

```
Public Function HexToByte(strHex As String) As Byte()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim tempByte As Byte
    Dim outBytes() As Byte
    ReDim outBytes(Len(strHex) \ 2 - 1)
    For i = 0 To Len(strHex) \ 2 - 1
        For j = 0 To 1
            char = Mid(strHex, i * 2 + j + 1, 1)
            Select Case char
                Case "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9":
                    tempByte = tempByte Or (Asc(char) - 48)
                Case "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F":
                    tempByte = tempByte Or (Asc(char) - 55)
            End Select
            If j = 0 Then
                tempByte = tempByte * 2 ^ 4
            Else
                outBytes(i) = tempByte
                tempByte = 0
            End If
        Next
    Next
    HexToByte = outBytes
End Function
```

Comment: Fantastic! Congrats BlackHawk, at the first test, this ran exactly as it should and I got the exact value of CRC8 as it is in my example Task! Thank you very much!

Comment: @AndroidNFC when modifying the code, I used [this online crc calculator to verify it](http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html).  For your implementation, the crc order is 8, the crc poly is 1D, the initial value is C7 and the Final XOR value is 0.  Unfortunately, the site doesn't allow entering data as hexadecimal bytes, so you can only do regular strings, but it still provides a good comparison to test an implementation against.